# Supress localNotification after an alertView is shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uilocalnotification

In my app a distance, set by the user, is watched. When the distance is covered an AlertView dialog is shown and a sound is played. By tapping the OK butten the alertView dissapear and the sound stops. When the app moves to the background the method UILocalNotification takes care of the sound and the message. This works ok. But...

When the app is in the foreground and the AlertView is shown and dismissed, the UILocalNotification method stays active. Thus when the app moves to the background it "plays" the local notification with the sound (again).

How could I avoid that behavior?

I want the message played once. In the foreground OR in the background. Not both. I've tried to solve this problem with an if() statement but that gives me unexpected results.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

when the user dismisses the alert in the foreground.

In case you need to have other local notifications active, just cancel the one in question.

Comment: Thank you! I'm in the right direction. Some unexpected bahavior, but I think I can figure it out. Otherwise..... stackoverflow.com is a great help!